# Terminal won't start, /var/lib/dpkg missing on new Raspbian install

Tags: raspbian, pixel

Just flashed with a new Raspbian image (20170111). Logs me into the terminal directly, so I `startx` with no issues, it loads Pixel.

The first problem is that the terminal application will not open. It absolutely does nothing. Chrome opens fine, as do some other apps, but not terminal.

So, I go to install `terminator` (which is the terminal I prefer anyways). Switch back to a different pseudo-term (CTRL-ALT-F2), and do `sudo apt-get install terminator`. It complains that `/var/lib/dpkg` is missing, which indeed it is.

Come back to the UI and open the package manager, but doing a search for anything always returns zero results.

I can't see this being a bad image as it boots just fine. It's just these two issues I can't seem to find a way to resolve.

Has anyone run into this on the most recent Raspbian? If so, any advice on how I can get past these issues?

Comment: After creating the `dpkg` directory and a slew others under it manually, I'm now reasonably successfully getting somewhere with the `apt-get` problem by following the highest-voted answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220649/problem-installing-packages/485293).

Comment: Did you verify the checksum on the downloaded image before installing it?

Comment: @Milliways I did. I'm starting to get a bit curious as to it being a `dd` issue now, as I'm seeing other slight oddities. It's a brand new card that I did some basic tests on before writing the image, but perhaps not enough. I think I'm going to buy another new card, and try another flash tomorrow on it and see if the same thing happens. `fsck` on the disk on another machine shows no errors, but I'm still not convinced I got a good copy to the drive. The link I put in my above comments did indeed fix my `apt-get` issues, I'm successfully installing now. If it works, I'll be good for today

Comment: well, as I was typing that on my laptop, the Pi froze solid, so I'll test another new card/flash tomorrow, and if that doesn't fix things, I'll try another Pi.